# PHP error displaying position. 

Tags: php, html, css

I have following PHP code:

```
            if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
            {
                echo '<p class="error">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</p>';
                unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
            }
```

Everything working fine. 'P' with error is displayed correctly inside  element.

My question is how to specify where my error should be displayed?

E.G. **Not as the first element inside the form, but**

- as the second for example
- just before `<input name="user" />`

??

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're (somewhat naively) testing for errors and displaying errors at the same time, you should just move the code lower in the page so that the test/output happen where you want it to display.

Ideally you should decouple your display code from your logic. Store your errors for later display in an `$errors` variable which is passed to your template to be rendered.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing - pasted in code is just tiny bit of it. I know that moving code would be simplest - but is there any more programming way to do it?

Comment: A "more programming" way would be the 2nd paragraph I mentioned: Distill your presentation logic out of your controller logic. Distill your business logic into models. Read up on MVC architecture.

Comment: in the any security issue with currently used method? Or is just bad programming?

Comment: @NewUser No "security issues" beyond a potential for outputting unescaped HTML/script, depending on how trustworthy the value of `$_SESSION['msg']['login-err']` is. You might consider `echo '<p class="error">', htmlspecialchars($_SESSION ...) ... `

Answer (score 1):

Rather than placing the echo where it exist now, why not change your code to something like this:

```
$error;
if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
{
    $error = $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
}
```

Then, right above your input tag, do something like this...

```
<?php echo $error;?>
```

It's not the best way to do error handling...but it should do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The "where" depends on you frontend design.

In a login form I would recommend to display errors at the top or bottom of the whole form. In a contact/registration form it makes more sense to show error beside the field ( on the top or left ).

Quite different thing is this combination of logic and presentations. They should be separated, because each piece of **code should have only one reason to change**. Your piece has two reasons: design or logic.

You would gain a lot if you did some extended studies in MVC and OOP in general.